# How to plot bar chart(s) from csv file using python?

Tags: python

I have this .csv file (that I can't edit):

```
,Denmark,Norway,Sweden

TotalCases,"78,354 ","35,546 ","243,129 "

Deaths,"823","328","6,681"

Recovered,"61,461","20,956",N/A
```

I want to make 3 separate bar charts/graphs , one for each section (TotalCases, Deaths, Recovered). However most guides I found online have the data presented the other way round, where the TotalCases are the columns instead of rows like in this scenario. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Then just transpose your data frame and follow the examples!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("""
country,Denmark,Norway,Sweden
TotalCases,"78,354 ","35,546 ","243,129 "
Deaths,"823","328","6,681"
Recovered,"61,461","20,956",N/A
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s)
df_t = df.transpose()
df_t.columns = df_t.iloc[0, :]
df_t = df_t.iloc[1:, :]
df_t['country'] = df_t.index
```

Use df_t then following their examples.

```
In [45]: df_t                                                                                         
Out[45]: 
country TotalCases Deaths Recovered  country
Denmark    78,354     823    61,461  Denmark
Norway     35,546     328    20,956   Norway
Sweden    243,129   6,681       NaN   Sweden
```